# Which method is overridden?

Tags: java, methods, interface, abstract, overriding

`Class A` has `run()` method and interface B also has `run()` method. Question is simple, which `run()` method is overridden in `Main` class and how will we prove this? Why there is no conflict (Compile-time error) in this code?

```
class A{
    void run(){System.out.println("A class");}
}

interface B{
    void run();
}

class Main extends A implements B{
    public static void main(String args[]){         
        Main m = new Main();
        m.run();
    }

    // Overridding method
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("run method");
    }
}
```

Comment: very curiously waiting for some expert answer

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`run` of `A` is overridden, `run` of `B` is implemented. As `B` is an interface, it only states how your objects behave to others and don't enforce any behavior itself.

Comment: so basicly `run` in `Main` that overrides `run` in `A` will meanwhile implement `run` of `B` ?

Comment: Yes. Anyone using `Main` can see by the interface `B` that `Main` will provide a method `run` - how this method is implemented, if it is inherited from a base class or implemented by `Main` itself is not relevant to users of `Main`.

Answer (score 3):

> `run()` Method of *Interface B* will be **Implemented** in *class Main* by
>   **overridden** method of *Class A*.

Adding an extra point,

It you will not write the `run()` method in child class `Main`, You will not get well known "Unimplemented methods" error. This is true for `public` methods of class A for non public methods you will get compiler error : *The inherited method can not hide public abstract method.*

That is because [methods of interface are public by default](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceDef.html) and you can not hide it with `default (package private)` access modifier.

Sample :

```
class A{
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("This method will be inherited.");
    }
}

interface B{
    void run();
}

class Main extends A implements B{
    public static void main(String args[]){         
        Main m = new Main();
        m.run();
    }
}
```

`OUTPUT : This method will be inherited.`

In above code instance, the `run()` method is inherited from class A that will implement `run()` method of interface B.

Answer (score 2):

There is no conflict because both methods have the same signature. Method declarations in interfaces are not overridden because they don't implement anything. So in this case, run method in class A is overridden.

On the other hand, when overriding methods you are encouraged to use the `@Override` annotation, e.g.

```
@Override
public void run() {
   ....
}
```

Comment: You are encouraged to use `@Override` when implementing interface methods as well.

Answer (score 2):

What will be called is

```
public void run(){
    System.out.println("run method");
}
```

Why?

You're implementing `run` of `interface B` and you're also *overriding* the `A` implementation of it.

If you remove the last `run()` implementation and remove `implements B`, `run()` of `A` will be called.

Answer (score 2):

Interface `B` says that any class implementing it must have a run method. Main extends A and inherits `A`'s `run()` method.

Main meets the requirement of the `B` interface for having a run method. The run method in Main then overrides the `run()` method it got from the `A` class.

```
// This is a class with a run method.
class A{
    void run(){System.out.println("A class");}
}

// Anything implementing this interface must have a run method.
interface B{
    void run();
}

// This class is an extension of A (and therefore has A's run() method)
// This class implements B and must have a run method, which it does, because it has A's
class Main extends A implements B{
    public static void main(String args[]){         
        Main m = new Main();
        m.run();
    }

    // This method then overrides the run Method it inherited from A
    // And this method meets the requirement set by implementing B.
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("run method");
    }
}
```

Comment: this explains why there is no compilation error , still a better explanation expected

Answer (score 0):

Super class's method is always called as `overridden` method whereas subclass method is called as `overriding` method.

Final method `cannot be` **overridden**. [if superclass's method is final]
Final methods `can` **override**. [Read it as grammatical way. This method is in subclass and is  final, but superclass's method is not final]